# Elegant way to create recursive directories

Tags: ruby

I have a directory structure similar to the one shown below. It goes 6 levels deep and in some cases there are two directories that need to be created at the same level. I would like to recursively create these directories.

```
pennsylvania
  bucks
    medicine
      pro
        bio
          a
          b
          c
        mental
          a
          b
          c
        physical 
          a
          b
          c
      non_pro
        bio
          a
          b
          c
        mental
          a
          b
          c
        physical 
          a
          b
          c
```

An ugly, and potentially buggy, approach would be like this:

```
unless File.exists?("pennsylvania")
  Dir.mkdir "pennsylvania"
end

unless File.exists?("pennsylvania/bucks")
  Dir.mkdir "pennsylvania/bucks"
end

unless File.exists?("pennsylvania/bucks/medicine")
  Dir.mkdir "pennsylvania/bucks/medicine"
end

unless File.exists?("pennsylvania/bucks/medicine/pro")
  Dir.mkdir "pennsylvania/bucks/medicine/pro"
end
```

And so on. You can see how inefficient this becomes as we navigate down the directory structure that needs to be created. I am seeking a more elegant solution. Something like this:

Using FileUtils class (albeit not part of standard library) makes it better:

```
['pro', 'non_pro'].each do |lev1|
  ['bio', 'mental', 'physical'].each do |lev2|
    ['a', 'b', 'c'].each do |lev3|
      FileUtils.mkdir_p "pennsylvania/bucks/medicine/#{lev1}/#{lev2}/#{lev3}"
    end
  end
end
```

Another benefit of FileUtils is it does not raise an exception if the directory already exists, and it doesn't seem to overwrite the directories (and the files in them) if the directory already exists.

The second solution I came up with is a big improvement on the first solution. But is there an even more elegant way?

Comment: Is there a more elegant way? Use a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileUtils.mkdir_p`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p) is a good choice, and it is part of the standard library.

You can use [`Array#product`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-product) to produce the tree.

```
levels = ['pro', 'non_pro'].product(
  ['bio', 'mental', 'physical'],
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
)
```

Then you can make your block work with any number of levels with [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join).

```
base = ["pennsylvania","bucks","medicine"]
levels.each do |level|
  FileUtils.mkdir_p( (base + level).join("/") )
end
```

---

Note that while this is very elegant, it is not the most efficient way to do it. The problem is every call to `FileUtils.mkdir_p` will try to make each subdirectory, and if it gets an error, check whether it already exists. For a small number of directories on a fast filesystem this is fine. But for a large tree or slow filesystem, such as a network filesystem, this can hurt performance.

For more efficient filesystem usage you'd do something like this recursion.

```
levels = [
  ['pennsylvania'],
  ['bucks'],
  ['medicine'],
  ['pro', 'non_pro'],
  ['bio', 'mental', 'physical'],
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
]

def make_subdirs(levels, base = [])
  return if levels.empty?

  levels[0].each { |dir|
    new_base = [*base, dir]
    mkdir_ignore_if_exists(new_base)
    make_subdirs(levels[1..-1], new_base)
  }
end

private def mkdir_ignore_if_exists(dirs)
  Dir.mkdir(dirs.join("/"))
rescue Errno::EEXIST
end

make_subdirs(levels)
```

Comment: Sometimes elegance is better than efficiency if it reinforces readability.

Comment: @Donato Elegant code isn't elegant if it takes five minutes to run. Necessary complexity for performance can be encapsulated, as I've done above. Like I said, this is only an issue for slow filesystems (sshfs, for example) or truly enormous directory trees (at which point you should consider a database).